# Pointer arithmetic in for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand some code that uses pointer arithmetic in a way I'm not used to. At one point in the code I encounter this:

```
complex<double> **P, *p_row, result=complex<double>(0,0);
P=new complex<double>*[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++) P[i]=new complex<double>[n];

for(i=0,p_row=*P;i<n;i++,p_row+=n) result+=log(*(p_row+i));
```

If P is a matrix, this looks to me like adding the logarithms of the diagonal elements of P. But it turns out the last line above is *not* equivalent to

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) result+=log(P[i][i]);
```

I've been searching for an explanation of what's going on here but I can't find it. Also, the code in question apparently gives the right result in the end (it's part of a Monte Carlo). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is wrong; it does invoke undefined behavior.

Eg. in the second iteration, `p_row` is `(*P)+n`. `*P` points to an array of size `n`, therefore, when the code reads `*(p_row+i)`, it reads past the end of the array.

The last line seems to assume the matrix is stored in a single continuous array (eg. row major). However, that means `P` would be a `complex<double>*` initialized by `P = new complex<double>[n*n];`.

Comment: Thanks for answers! The weird thing is, the (first) code actually works; the calculation gives the correct result.. Is it possible that the code is a lot of the time working outside allotted memory but in a consistent way, so that every element although outside its matrix is still used correctly? That's the only explanation I can think of but that sounds like it would be a complete mess.

Comment: @AndreyT: I see! But shouldn't that imply that the last line in the undefined code and the one with P[i][i] in the next snippet give the same?

Comment: @jorgen: I deleted my comment, because it was incorrect. Additional household data stored in each allocated memory block should make these independent array non-contiguous. So, I don't really know how the fist variant of the code can possibly work. Moreover, I'm pretty sure it won't work correctly, if you fill your matrix elements with different unique values.

Comment: @jorgen: Basically, it is perfectly possible that by doing `p_row += n` you happen to jump out of one array and straight into the next one (by pure luck). However, it should not result in access to *diagonal* elements specifically. The access should get "misaligned" and the element in the next array should not be the diagonal one. If you see the "correct" result from the first code, it is probably because your matrix contains many identical values.

Comment: @AndreyT: I'm sorry I think I was a bit unclear; the code (which is a small extract from a long one) is not necessarily made to access diagonal elements, that was just my guess as to what was going on there. But the code as a whole works, not because of equal elements I think, it is too complicated for that. I was wondering if say the snippet above actually is meant to access diagonal elements but accesses others instead, however in a consistent way so that it ends up with the right ones anyway. However that seems unlikely since we'd be working outside allocated memory.

Comment: @jorgen: Well, as I said, given that the individual rows are allocated immediately one after another, it is very likely that the first version of the code actually works *inside* allocated memory (by pure luck). But in any case there are no meaningful guarantees about this code.

Comment: I think I've figured this out now, and I think there is no undefined behaviour here. In the loop `(i=0,p_row=*P;i<n;i++,p_row+=n)`, for every iteration n is added to p_row. In e.g. the second run, this means that `p=*P+n`, NOT that `p=*(P+n)`. Thus at iteration i we have `p_row=*P+n*i+i`. On my system this still doesn't access the diagonal though; it seems after every row of the matrix (picturing the double pointer as a matrix) there is an unused memory location. Therefore, for me `(i=0,p_row=*P;i<n;i++,p_row+=n+1)` accesses the diagonal. I don't know if this depends on compiler etc.

Answer (score 2):

The loop with `p_row+=n` exhibits undefined behavior, because it assumes that the allocations done by the loop on the third line are contiguous, but in nearly all implementations they are not.

Your code with `P[i][i]` retrieves the correct result. You can fix the other code by allocating `n*n` elements in a single shot, and then parceling them out into `p` in a loop.